# Exception when I parse XML file

Tags: java, xml, encoding

when i call mehtod `getIdFromDatabase`for get id from my XML database but show me `exception [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Call method `getIdFromDatabase`:

```
nameLayer =getIdLayerFromDatabase("//Project/Layer[Name="+"'"+Name+"'"+"]/@idLayer","ProjectDataBase.xml");
```

Method in java:

```
 public int getIdFromDatabase(String PathXPath, String Path) throws JAXBException {
            int maxid = -1, id = -1;
            DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                //***** exception here****************************** 
                Document dDoc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(Path.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
                XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
                NodeList nl = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(PathXPath, dDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    id = Integer.parseInt(nl.item(i).getNodeValue());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return id;
        }
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://www.example.org/ProjectDataBase" name="شئؤ" location="Projects//شئؤ//ProjectDataBase.xml" CreationDate="2014-07-20">
   <Layer idLayer="0">
      <Name>طبقة  1</Name>
   </Layer>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to parse the path and not the file. Change the line:

```
Document dDoc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(Path.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

by:

```
Document dDoc = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(Path));
```